# Glusterfs can't set xattr security.selinux

Tags: docker, glusterfs

I'm currently trying to use Gluster as storage for docker volumes on Centos 7.
The gluster version is 4.0.2.

On creation of the volume the files from the container are copied to the new volume. The volume is stored in a gluster mounted directory using the gluster client (no NFS).

Upon copying the first file I get this error:

```
dockerd: time="2018-06-29T16:54:42.0
5675816+02:00" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="failed to copy xattrs: failed to set xattr \"security.selinux\" on /var/lib/docker/volumes/test_laravelstorage/_data/app/.gitignore: operation not supported" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=zfqlnpdchcaa0xl0vs8ck0ec7 dervice.id=e94kmsgqq222ohssk6is866la task.id=k9efjmil9sgmeza507z9r7qy
```

Selinux is disabled.

Looking at the specs of GlusterFs security.selinux should be supported. Am I doing something wrong or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

No xattr enabled at glusterfs server side brick mount?
Verify mount options for brick volumes.

http://lists.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-devel/2011-May/036005.html

Answer (score 1):

Setting SELinux contexts is currently not supported on FUSE filesystems. This needs to be fixed in the FUSE Linux kernel module, and added support to Gluster as well.

Work and (very slow) progress on this is tracked in [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1230671).